# How to detect if user shares Application Url

Tags: facebook, url, share, status

I have an application on Facebook.

I would like to know how can I manage to detect if the user shares the URL of the application (the user copy-pastes the link of the app) on his status ?

I need to do that because people that sees this application must be redirected to a fan page, before seeing the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In you application you can FQL to see if visiting user is fan of fan page and redirect him if not.

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = <page_id>
```

[More on FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)